# How to Iterate the data from the multiple innner maps in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have the data in the format of @Person,ID,ID1,ID2,ID3,[Job,JID,JID1,JID2],[Student,SID,SID1,SID2],[COURSE,CID,CID1].

Now I need to store this information in a map. That means I want to put person data first and then check whether there is any Job data or not. If Job data is there then put Job data and check again for whether there is any Student data or not.  If Student data is there then put Student data and check for remaining data and so on.

Note:
The Person data, Job data, Student data, and Course data should be of individual maps, referred from the parent map Person.

In this scenario, how do we iterate the data from these maps?

Please do let me know if my question is not clear.

Please provide your thoughts to get rid of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how your maps are set up.  How many maps do you have, and what are their keys?

Comment: i have a total of four maps and keys will be any user defined strings of unique.

Comment: Will Person 1 and Job 1 have the same unique string?

Comment: Sounds a bit weird to me, can you post the code maybe? Why do you want to use maps for your problem?

Comment: no person1 keys are diferent from job1 keys. my project has some custom code which asks us to set the data for maps. thats why i am using maps.